# How do I query for nil values with CloudKit.js?

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

Using CloudKit.js, how do I construct a query that matches items where a field is nil? Every permutation I've tried fails - either it's clearly matching on a string value (i.e. "null" or "nil") or it throws an error if I actually try to pass 'null'.

Any ideas? None of the below work.

```
filterBy: [{
        fieldName: 'customerNumber',
        comparator: 'EQUALS',
        fieldValue: { value: "nil" }
}]

filterBy: [{
        fieldName: 'customerNumber',
        comparator: 'EQUALS',
        fieldValue: { value: null }
}]

filterBy: [{
        fieldName: 'customerNumber',
        comparator: 'EQUALS',
        fieldValue: { value: "null" }
}]

filterBy: [{
        fieldName: 'customerNumber',
        comparator: 'EQUALS',
        fieldValue: { value: "" }
}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is any option to query for nil values in CloudKit. Also not from native code. I have tried a lot of predicates, but non seems to work.

You do have to be aware that CloudKit is a key-value store. When a value is nil, then the key won't be there in the record. There is no option to query for non existing keys.

The closest I have come to a good solution was with a predicate with the format `"NOT myField => ''"` sorry, don't know the format for .js

In the [CloudKit CKQuery documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/) there is nothing mentioned about nil fields.

In the [documentation for NSPredicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)  there are sample's for nil values.

But it was already clear that CloudKit has implemented only a subset of the possibilities of NSPredicate (see CKQuery class reference)

I think the best way to handle this is by not using/depending on nil values. If you do need to check some nil status, then instead you could add an extra field that would represent that status.

Comment: You may be right. I submitted this to DTS and will either accept your answer or submit whatever their alternative ends up being. Thanks.

Comment: Heard back from DTS and you are indeed correct. I guess it's time to file an enhancement Radar.